# В NGINX узнать авторизированного имя пользователя зашедшего в закрытую директорию сайта

Tags: linux, nginx

Сделал закрытую директорию.

```
http {
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;

    root /var/www/html;
    auth_basic "Введите пароль для входа";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpassw;
}
```

}

В базе данных записана действия пользователей.

Как узнать имя пользователя, прошедшего аутентификацию, чтобы отобразить ему нужную страницу с данными?

Comment: `отобразить ему нужную страницу с данными` - какая логика должна быть? вы хотите это на Nginx разрулить и подсунуть нужную страницу, или в скрипте?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте на предмет $remote_user тут:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user

Comment: Но ТС кажется спрашивал как вытащить этот `$remote_user` в скрипте, чтобы запустить какую-то логику...

Comment: ТС не указал из каких скриптов, потому и ответ такой